# How to create a column that sums up occurrences in other column

Tags: r

So, I want to create a column that sums up the number of case occurrences per person. So right now the data set looks like this:

```
data

Date                   Casenum                      Name
12/16                    1                          Smith, John
12/16                    2                          Smith, John
12/16                    3                          Smith, John 
12/16                    4                          Smith, John
01/17                    5                          Smith, John
01/17                    6                          Smith, John
02/17                    8                          Black, Jack
```

And I want it to look something like this (for a new dataset):

```
cno_data

Name                              cno (# of cases)
Smith, John                            6
Black, Jack                            1
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Try `aggregate(Name ~ Casenum, data, length)` or `table(data[-1])`

Comment: What's wrong with `table(data$Name)`?

Comment: Thank you! The table function worked

Answer (score 0):

The other suggestions will work, but may or may not be flexible for your needs. I recommend that you do your data wrangling with the dplyr package. dplyr has a built in `count()` function that will return another dataframe, as you have requested. This might make the data easier to work with in the future if you need to extract this information.

```
library(dplyr)
cno_data <- count(data, Names)

print(cno_data)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
Name            n
<fct>       <int>
1 Black, Jack     1
2 Smith, John     6
```

Using dplyr will also allow you to do other things such as group and summarise your data. You can view the documentation here -> [dplyr](http://127.0.0.1:27067/library/dplyr/doc/dplyr.html)